# Subir Archivos con Php y jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

el tema es el siguiente estoy tratando de subir un archivo con jquery y php el codigo es el siguiente:

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="archivo" class="control-label col-xs-5">Comprobante:</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <input placeholder="Subir Comprobante en PDF" name="archivo" id="archivo" type="file" class="file">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="Observacion" class="control-label col-xs-5">Observacion :</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">

                                            <textarea name="Observacion" id="Observacion"  class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

**mi codigo jquery:**

```
function registrarInc(){

    var datosform=$("#formIncidencia").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:'../Controllers/Incidencia.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:datosform+"&registrarInc=registrarInc",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function(resp){

        if(resp==='exito'){
            $('#exitoInc').show(200).delay(2500).hide(200);
            $('#formIncidencia')[0].reset();
        }
        else{
            alert(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

**mi php en el lado del controlador**

```
if ($boton==='registrarInc') {

    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;
$inst = new Incidencia();
    if ($nombre != "") {

        if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
            $empleado=$_POST['idEmp'];
        $diasolicitado=$_POST['diasolicitado'];
        $tipodejustificacion=$_POST['tipodejustificacion'];
        $Observacion=$_POST['Observacion'];
            $Autorizo="";
            if($inst->registrarInc($empleado,$diasolicitado,$tipodejustificacion,$Observacion,$Autorizo,$nombre,$tamanio,$tipo)){
            echo 'exito';
        }
        } else{
            echo "No se registraron los datos";
        }
    }
}
```

**y mi php en lado modelo:**

```
function registrarInc($empleado,$diasolicitado,$tipodejustificacion,$Observacion,$Autorizo,$nombre,$tamanio,$tipo)
        {

        $sql="INSERT INTO `incidencias`(`empleado`, `diasolicitado`, `tipodejustificacion`, `Observacion`,Autorizo, `nombre_archivo`, `tamanio`, `tipo`) values($empleado,$diasolicitado,$tipodejustificacion,$Observacion,$Autorizo,$nombre,$tamanio,$tipo)";
            $this->conexion->conexion->set_charset('utf8');
            if($this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
            $this->conexion->cerrar();
        }

el error que me arroja es que mis variables
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;
```

no tienen valor definido en el lado del controlador de mi archivo php.

Agradeceria si alguien me puediera auxiliar.

Comment: Puede ser que en tu form no estés declarando el `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, puedes ver más en la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: de ante mano muchas gracias por tu respuesta, te comento, efectivamente no tenia agrgado en mi form enctype="multipart/form-data" ya lei el apartado de php donde explica como funciona el script para subir un archivo en php, el caso es que me di ala tarea de ´probar mi codigo solo en php dejando aun lado el jquery y el script funciona sin problema, el error viene cuando trato de usar jquery con php

Comment: Talves esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously/8758614#8758614) de SO en inglés te sirva :D

Comment: ya el problema quedo solucionado, mi problema era que estaba utilizando en jquery var datosform=$("#formIncidencia").serialize(); y en ves de eso utilice var datosform = new FormData($("#formIncidencia")[0]); y listo funciono de maravilla